# Python string representation of binary data

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand the way Python displays strings representing binary data.

Here's an example using [os.urandom](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.urandom)

```
In [1]: random_bytes = os.urandom(4)

In [2]: random_bytes
Out[2]: '\xfd\xa9\xbe\x87'

In [3]: random_bytes = os.urandom(4)

In [4]: random_bytes
Out[4]: '\r\x9eq\xce'
```

In the first example of `random_bytes`, after each \x there seem to be values in hexadecimal form: fd a9 be 87.

In the second example, however, I don't understand why `'\r\x9eq\xce'` is displayed.

Why does Python show me these random bytes in this particular representation? How should I interpret `'\r\x9eq\xce'`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's only using the `\xHH` notation for characters that are (1) non-printable; and (2) don't have a shorter [escape sequence](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/strings.html).

To examine the hex codes, you could use the [`binascii`](http://docs.python.org/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify) module:

```
In [12]: binascii.hexlify('\r\x9eq\xce')
Out[12]: '0d9e71ce'
```

As you can see:

- `\r` is the same as `\x0d` (it's the ASCII Carriage Return character, CR);
- `q` is the same as `\x71` (the latter is the hex [ASCII code](http://www.asciitable.com/) of the former).

Comment: "It's only using the \xHH notation for characters that are (1) non-printable; and (2) don't have a shorter escape sequence." Why is it so? Is there a way to prevent this, and see the hex representation instead of printable character or the escape sequence?

Answer (score 3):

\r is a carriage return, q is the q character - you should refer to their ASCII values (0x0d and 0x71)

Whenever python can - it will display the corresponding ASCII character, you'll only see \x when it can't (usually when the byte is higher than 0x79)